# How to post a list of strings to GAE

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, google-app-engine

How to properly POST a list of strings with jQuery to Google App Engine app? I create something like this:

```
$.post("/add", {tags:['first tag','second tag','third tag']}
```

And then in FireBug I see it becomes something like this:

```
tags%5B%5D=first tag&tags%5B%5D=second tag&tags%5B%5D=third tag
```

I am not sure I send a list properly. If it's fine, then how to process this list with Python?
I try to use something like this:

```
tagsList = self.request.get("tags")
```

But without much success.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution would be to cast `self.request.get("tags")` in a `list()` however this doesn't work with me when I send a javascript array, but maybe it would work for your case

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize it into a JSON string, and this string will be treated as the post data.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/add",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({tags:['first tag','second tag','third tag']}),
```

Parses the data for example (in Java):

```
    try {
        reader = request.getReader();
    } catch (final IllegalStateException illegalStateException) {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                request.getInputStream()));
    }

    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (null != line) {
        sb.append(line);
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    reader.close();

    String tmp = sb.toString();
    if (Strings.isEmptyOrNull(tmp)) {
        tmp = "{}";
    }

    return new JSONObject(tmp);
```